# Cannot create react project

Tags: reactjs

following a crash (eg blue screen), i no longer can create a react project. i've removed and reinstalled node, but i'm still dead out of water. any ideas appreciated tia.

every time i type 'create-react-app client' for example, i get the following message:

error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v4\npm-autoprefixer-9.7.4-f8bf3e06707d047f0641d87aee8cfb174b2a5378\node_modules\autoprefixer\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected token \u0000 in JSON at position 0".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "c:\abc\project_folder\client\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd c:\abc\project_folder\client has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.

Comment: Given the error: clear your Yarn cache first?